# python 3 and macos Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system

Tags: python, macos, pip

I am on mac os trying to install cython.  I have zero clue how to resolve.

```
pip3 install cython
Collecting cython
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9b/e6/6e30303d7bc17289411d82276b7338a1781964171c94f5ebe689cbecad4c/Cython-0.29.14-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
Installing collected packages: cython
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/lib'
```

Comment: Did you read the error message???

Comment: Try running the command as admin or change 4755 chmod for pip3

Comment: Hey @bruno-desthuilliers get real.  Did you?

Comment: using sudo gives same error

Answer (score 0):

This solved my issue on mac os by running in a terminal:

```
   xcode-select --install
```

Then restart.  Somehow with the lastest mac update, things got messed up.

The problem with pip was global